# How to efficiently get all the rows from a huge table in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two tables `users` and `notes` with more than 50k records in users and 90k records in notes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end
```

Schema of users_table:

```
id  email  created_at
```

Schema of notes_table:

```
id  user_id  created_at category impact_score
```

I am trying to create a temporary table `temp_user_notes` which can have data of both the tables on which i can perform ActiveRecord queries to fetch the data.

Schema of user_notes_table:

```
id  user_id  notes_id  email user_created_at notes_created_at category impact_score
```

I am doing this

```
def self.populate_temp_user_notes
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      user.notes.each do |note|
        user_notes = TempUserNote.new
        user_notes.user_id = user.id
        user_notes.notes_id = note.id
        user_notes.auth_token_created_at = user.auth_token_created_at
        user_notes.notes_recorded_at = note.recorded_at
        user_notes.category = note.category
        user_notes.well_being_score = note.perception_score
        user_notes.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Looping through all the uses and their notes is very long memory eating process what other approach can i use?

EDIT From here:-

My requirement is: I have series of queries seperated by AND and OR Conditions that take use of folowing table: users, notes, transactions,  subscription. suppose my query to get target users is  `(Query1 OR Query2) AND Query3 AND Query4`
then output of every query is input of next query.

eg:

```
total users in DB = 1000
1. user_list =  (Query1 or Query2) #=> 500 users
2. taking 500 users from user_list as input for next query
3. user_list = user_list AND Query3  #=> 300 users
4. taking 300 users from point 3 as input for query in point 4
5. user_list = user_list AND Query4 #=> 50 users
```

in the last user list i have my target users and there notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a combination of [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) and [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) to decrease both: memory usage and the number of database queries:

```
def self.populate_temp_user_notes
  User.includes(:notes).find_each do |user|
    user.notes.each do |note|
      TempUserNote.create(
        user_id:               user.id,
        notes_id:              note.id,
        auth_token_created_at: user.auth_token_created_at,
        notes_recorded_at:     note.recorded_at,
        category:              note.category,
        well_being_score:      note.perception_score,
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Another very fast option might be to do this with in plain SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp_user_notes
  (user_id, notes_id, auth_token_created_at, notes_recorded_at, category, well_being_score)
  SELECT users.id, notes.id, users.auth_token_created_at, notes.recorded_at, notes.category, notes.perception_score
    FROM users INNER JOIN notes ON users.id = notes.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

With huge amounts of data, it would never be beneficial to use `User.all`. Imagine extracting 50k rows of data, and then for each row, making a brand new object of `User` class, and populating that object with the data in that row. Yes, it's gonna create trouble(s) for you, and Rails is aware of it.

You can use:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  # do your thing
end
```

`find_each` will give you 1000 records at one time, thus reducing memory operations.

You can overwrite the default value by providing `batch_size` in `find_each`:

```
User.find_each(batch_size: 3000) do |user|
  # do your thing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am trying to create a temporary table temp_user_notes which can have data of both the tables on which i can perform ActiveRecord queries to fetch the data.*

The more standard way of doing this is simply to **join the two tables**. If you use the following clause:

```
User.joins(:notes)
```

then this will give you a scope that can be used for further querying (you can e.g. add `where` conditions on both tables) and the returned records will include columns from both the `User` and `Note` models, e.g.:

```
User.joins(:notes).where("notes.impact_score > 10")
```

Will give you all notes with a high-enough score, together with their attached users.

If you need to go through all the joined records, you should use the [`find_each` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) that returns the records in batches.

Comment: I agree @BoraMa to use joins is efficient way to do this but doing this doesnt solves my purpose.
My requirement is: I have series of queries seperated by AND and OR Conditions. eg: 
1. user_list =  (Query1 or Query2)  
2. taking user_list as input
3. user_list = user_list AND Query3
4. user_list = user_list(fulfillig condition 3) AND Query4

in the last user list i have my target users and there notes.